# Facebook Graph api explorer: "with=picture" modifier not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve my facebook feed which has the place/picture field. I still see some posts which do not have a picture or place. I am using

```
me/feed?fields=story,picture&with=picture
```

or

```
me/feed?fields=story,place&with=place
```

in the graph api explorer. Both of these return results without the place/picture fields. Something strange I observed was when I used this

```
me/feed?fields=story,place&with=location&limit=1000
```

I retrieve only the posts which have place tag. Although location is a field inside place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from Facebook developer community. with modifier can be used only for location.

Comment: please edit the answer and link to the information source (permalink to post in group)